# Eloqua Data Retrieval options for Campaigns

Tags: eloqua, eloqua-bulk-api

I am trying to export campaigns and campaign responses data through the API but I am unable to do so. Is there any other way to do it?

Tried using the api endpoints as per the eloqua documentation. I am able to fetch all the campaign names and field names through it but not the actual data